# Why do tcp applications send a reset segment after close()ing the connection with data unread in the tcp receive buffer?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, buffer

I've noticed that whenever I call close() from a TCP application and unread data is still inside the TCP receiving buffer the application sends a RST segment.

1)Is this the default behaviour of any TCP protocol or is OS dependent ? (I'm working on Mac Os);

2)How can I prevent the application from sending a RST segment and allow it to send a FIN even with unread data in the buffer ? Is there any way to flush this data and make the app think it has read anything?

3)Why did tcp engineers decide to implement this behaviour ?

Here is the client and server code respectively. I let the client close the connection with the '#' character still in the TCP receiving buffer on purpose :

```
int main(){


int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
//CREATE SOCKET
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    //Server ip and port
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));  
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT_SERVER);
    
    

if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        if(errno == ECONNREFUSED){
            printf("Host service inactive on the specified port \n");
        }
        else if(errno == ETIMEDOUT || errno == EHOSTUNREACH){
            printf("Connection timed out ! The server could not be reached \n");
        }else{
            printf("Connection could not be established \n");
        }
        errno = 0;
        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
    }


char buff;
while((read(sockfd,&buff,sizeof(buff))) > 0){
     if(buff =='\n'){
     write(1,&buff,sizeof(buff));
     break;
     }
     write(1,&buff,sizeof(buff));
};
close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

---

```
int main(){

 int sockfd, connfd;
 unsigned int len;
 struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

//SOCKET CREATION
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }


bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if ((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

if ((listen(sockfd,128)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

for(;;){

len = sizeof(cli);

connfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cli, &len);

if (connfd < 0) {
        printf("server accept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

char hello[7]={'H','e','l','l','o','\n','#'};
write(connfd,hello,sizeof(hello));
char buffr;
int r;
while( (r=read(connfd,&buffr,sizeof(buffr))) > 0 ){}
       close(connfd);
};

return 0;

}
```

Comment: That's standard TCP behavior. You should read normally until `read` or `recv` returns `0`.

Answer (score 2):

To send a FIN use `shutdown(connfd, SOCK_WR)`. Then, you keep reading until there is nothing left to read (read or recv returns 0), which means the other computer also sent a FIN. Then, you close the socket.

To my knowledge it is like this on all operating systems. `RST` is sent if another computer sends a packet to a nonexistent socket. By sending an `RST` when you close the socket, even if another packet wasn't received yet, your computer is being very slightly more polite by telling the other computer it's not listening any more.